# Can't use string literal "s" with a string in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a simple C++ program that would just print string "Hello" with a string literal **s**. However, for some reason I can't. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string hello_word = "Hello!"s;
    cout << hello_word << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error code:

```
test.cpp:7:33: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    string hello_word = "Hello!"s;
                                ^
                                ;
1 error generated.
```

I've tried inserting `using namespace std::string_literals` but nothing still works.

Comment: Using `using namespace std::string_literals;` works just fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d5ce7f9ca611ca8)

Comment: @NathanOliver for some reason, it doesn't work for me. Here is the error: test.cpp:5:22: error: expected namespace name
using namespace std::string_literals;

Comment: What compiler and version?

Comment: Are you compiling using C++14 or newer?

Comment: Ohh, yes, this was a version problem, guys... Thank you for yor help!!